# VS2015: The type 'XXX' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced while debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I can't seem to debug PCL library (using a very simple test project). When breakpoint hits and watch window reloads, it throws `CS0012: The type 'TaskAwaiter<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.` Local and auto windows remain empty.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 RTM (I didn't upgrade from any previous versions - it's a clean install from ISO) on Windows 10 Pro (clean install as well). My test project targets Windows Phone 8.1 and I debug using an actual device.

I found a couple of references to a similiar bug, but it occurred during building the solution. In my case, solution builds just fine, no errors or warnings.
I tried adding `System.Threading.Tasks.dll` manually, but VS won't let me - it says it's added automatically by build system.

Has anyone came across this issue as well (and hopefully fixed it)?

Comment: The message is accurate, TaskAwaiter is not available on a phone.  How you got a dependency on it is harder to guess.  Note the null PublicKeyToken, that's pretty bad.  Verify that the PCL project targets include phone 8.1, document any Nuget packages you use.

Comment: same here, in my case the code that can't be debugged is located in a **shared code** project

Comment: Exactly the same issue. Very annoying as the only way I can debug is writing out to the console :(

Comment: I am also facing this issue, and have not yet found a solution. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't have any. I went back to my old Windows 8.1 and VS2013.

Comment: @eggplant so you are thinking that this is an issue in Visual Studio 2015 then?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark: Oh, absolutely.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've had exactly the same error CS0012: ...TaskAwaiter<>...
This is a known issue in VS2015.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025133

To solve it go to Debug - Options - General - Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluator (tick)

Comment: This solved my problems when debugging Windows Phone apps directly on the device (I always got error CS0012 in the immediate window before).

Comment: It doesn't help to me, I just got a new error "The value is unobtainable now"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for me to solve this CS0012 error issue in this [Blog](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31112/new-project-out-of-the-box-so-to-speak-assembly-not-found-system-runtime).
Just added reference to the missing dlls from :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades"
```

and the errors disappeared.

Comment: There is a missing backslash but due to the idiotic 6 char edit rule I cannot edit this.  Correct path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades

Answer (score 0):

(Since I have not enough reputation to comment, I have to write a new answer...)

Be sure to **stop debugging** before trying to check the *Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators* box. Otherwise it will be grayed out.